# GitLab with Docker on Synology NAS - HTTPS

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, synology, gitlab-omnibus

I would like to set up GitLab with https on Synology DS918+.

I am using DOCKER in DSM. I downloaded the latest GitLab Community docker image.

[image]

And I used Putty to ssh into the NAS and create keys using openssl.

1) Create a key into cert folder:

```
mkdir /volume1/docker/gitlab/certs
cd /volume1/docker/gitlab/certs
openssl genrsa -out gitlab.key 2048
openssl req -new -key gitlab.key -out gitlab.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in gitlab.csr -signkey gitlab.key -out gitlab.crt
openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
chmod 400 gitlab.key
```

2) I added two additional variables in custom image to set up the environment for HTTPS:

[image]

3) In the last part:

- I remove port 80 that was first set in the default image.
- And add ports 30000/30001 for 22/443 port bindings that were set to auto in the default image:

[image]

When I go to browser for https://synologyip.com:30000 GitLab can't be reached.

Any guesses on what have I missed or done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean GitLab can't be reached? Is it a 5XX error? Is the webserver not answering?

Comment: Same issue for me...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about you, but I had to create the cert in the following folder:

/volume1/docker/gitlab/gitlab/certs

Note the repeated gitlab directory

Answer (score 0):

A good well-written tutorial can be found here: [Github Tutorial](https://gist.github.com/mattcarlotta/4d9fdb90376c5d13db2c1b69a2d557a6), and with a letsencrypt cert too!

Although i shortened the cert copy part like follows:

```
 cat /usr/syno/etc/certificate/_archive/*/privkey.pem > /volume1/docker/github/github/certs/gitlab.key

 cat /usr/syno/etc/certificate/_archive/*/fullchain.pem > /volume1/docker/github/github/certs/gitlab.crt
```

and continued then with the dhparam.pem

Comment: Since you are formally posting an answer to an older question. It would be most helpful that you support your purported answer with some code and the output that results from using your code.

Comment: I thought resisted of describing the Github tutorial here too since I couldn't have done it better and all of the steps are straightforward explained there (except the to commands I've posted). Should I rewrite it anyway?

Comment: @DorianGaensslen, do you have to set up the DDNS stuff or will the cert stuff suffice?

Comment: @EmmanuelF the DDNS stuff has to be set up also because otherwise, the Cert will be untrusted. The whole Cert part applies only if you want to have a trusted cert. If not, you could create a self signed and copy it on the NAS instead